# Filter neo4j nodes by subtracting nodes that are returned by index

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

My nodes have an array property `category_ids` that contains integers.

I can query for nodes whose `category_ids` do not match any in the list [1,2,3]:

```
START node(*)
WHERE NOT(ANY(x in node.category_ids WHERE x IN [1,2,3]))
RETURN node;
```

I can use an index (I'm calling it `nodes_categories` and it's a standard exact lucene index) to start with the nodes that I want to filter out:

```
START excluded=node:nodes_categories("category_ids:(1 2 3)")
RETURN excluded;
```

But how do I use my index to get the nodes I *do* want?  IE return all the nodes minus the nodes returned by my index hit?  Here's my start:

```
START node=node(*), excluded=node:nodes_categories("category_ids:(1 2 3)")
???
RETURN node;
```

Edit: neo4j version is 1.9.M02

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naive way (updated):

```
START node=node(*), excluded=node:nodes_categories("category_ids:(1 2 3)")
WITH collect(excluded) as excluded, node
WHERE not node in(excluded)
RETURN distinct node;
```

A better way would be to figure out how to query the index for just the nodes you want. I'm not sure if there is a way to do it in the lucene syntax, though. Maybe something like:

```
START node=node:nodes_categories('category_ids:(* NOT 1 NOT 2 NOT 3)')
return node;
```

Comment: The naive way seems to work only if the index hit returns a single node, otherwise it returns all the nodes including those in the index hit.

The better way does indeed work.  But I want to include nodes missing from the index so I'd really like to get the naive way to work.

Comment: Also the naive way returns 0 nodes all together if the index hit returns 0 nodes.  I can safely assume the index hit will return at least 1 node, but am pointing this out to help figure out what's going on.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I guess I didn't think it all the way through.

Comment: Here's a second attempt. It uses a collect so the efficiency might not be great.